# Make lines of bars thicked in stacked bar chart

Tags: r, ggplot2

In the stacked bar below I want to make the lines of the bars thicked in order to distinguish the different groups. I used size but it does not work.

```
Cum<-structure(list(Age.group = c("00-04", "00-04", "05-14", "05-14", 
                                  "15-24", "15-24", "25-49", "25-49", "50-64", "50-64", "65-79", 
                                  "65-79", "80+", "80+"), Gender = c("Female", "Male", "Female", 
                                                                     "Male", "Female", "Male", "Female", "Male", "Female", "Male", 
                                                                     "Female", "Male", "Female", "Male"), Cases = c(64578, 70518, 
                                                                                                                    187568, 197015, 414405, 388138, 1342394, 1206168, 792180, 742744, 
                                                                                                                    400232, 414613, 282268, 198026), lab = c("64,578", "70,518", 
                                                                                                                                                             "187,568", "197,015", "414,405", "388,138", "1,342,394", "1,206,168", 
                                                                                                                                                             "792,180", "742,744", "400,232", "414,613", "282,268", "198,026"
                                                                                                                    ), Age.group.Sum = c(135096, 135096, 384583, 384583, 802543, 
                                                                                                                                         802543, 2548562, 2548562, 1534924, 1534924, 814845, 814845, 480294, 
                                                                                                                                         480294), lab2 = c("135,096", "135,096", "384,583", "384,583", 
                                                                                                                                                           "802,543", "802,543", "2,548,562", "2,548,562", "1,534,924", 
                                                                                                                                                           "1,534,924", "814,845", "814,845", "480,294", "480,294"), color = c("#4285f4", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                               "#4285f4", "#90a9e0", "#90a9e0", "#dd9e5f", "#dd9e5f", "#b45f06", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                               "#b45f06", "#b45f06", "#b45f06", "#dd9e5f", "#dd9e5f", "#aebbd6", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                               "#90a9e0"), Range = c("LESS THAN 74.5K", "LESS THAN 74.5K", "148.9K - 223.4K", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     "148.9K - 223.4K", "372.3K - 446.7K", "372.3K - 446.7K", "MORE THAN 670.1K", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     "MORE THAN 670.1K", "MORE THAN 670.1K", "MORE THAN 670.1K", "372.3K - 446.7K", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     "372.3K - 446.7K", "223.4K - 297.8K", "148.9K - 223.4K")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    -14L))
library(scales)
library(ggplot2)
names(mycols) <- mycols
ylab <- c(0.5,1,1.5,2,2.5)
lbls <- setNames(unique(Cum$color), unique(Cum$Range))


ggplot_obj <- ggplot(data = Cum, aes(x = `Age.group`, y = Cases, group = Gender,fill = Range)) +
  geom_bar(aes(
    
    text = paste("<b>Gender:</b>", Gender, "<br><b>Age:</b>", `Age.group` ,
                 "<br><b>Cases:</b>", lab, "<br><b>Total cases in age group:</b>",
                 lab2)), 
    position = "stack", stat = "identity",size=5) +
  geom_text(aes(y = Cases + 10000, label = Gender), vjust = 1,
            position = position_dodge(width=0.9),size=2) +
  scale_fill_manual(values = lbls) +
  coord_cartesian(ylim = c(0, max(Cum$Cases)*1.1), expand = FALSE) +
  theme_bw()+ theme(
    # remove the vertical grid lines
    panel.grid.major.x = element_blank(),
    panel.border = element_blank(), axis.line.x = element_line()
  ) +
  scale_y_continuous(labels = unit_format(unit = "M", scale = 1e-6))+
  xlab("Age group") 
ggplot_obj
```

Comment: Do you mean the borders of the bars? Maybe try with adding a `color` e.g. `color = "white"` to make the borders visible.

Comment: yes those I mean

Comment: In that case try with setting the color. By default the borders get the same color as used for the fill. That's why increasing the size had no (visible) effect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default the color of border & the bar are the same. For your case you may need to specify a `color` outside `mapping`. And as you are drawing the title for the bar I recommend using `position = "dodge"` instead of stack.

```r
ggplot_obj <- ggplot(data = Cum, aes(x = `Age.group`, y = Cases, group = Gender,fill = Range)) +
  geom_bar(aes(
    text = paste("<b>Gender:</b>", Gender, "<br><b>Age:</b>", `Age.group` ,
      "<br><b>Cases:</b>", lab, "<br><b>Total cases in age group:</b>",
      lab2)), color = "black",
    position = "dodge", stat = "identity",size=0.01) +
  geom_text(aes(y = Cases + max(Cum$Cases)*.02, label = Gender), vjust = 1,
    position = position_dodge(width=0.9),size=2) +
  scale_fill_manual(values = lbls) +
  coord_cartesian(ylim = c(0, max(Cum$Cases)*1.1), expand = FALSE) +
  theme_bw()+ theme(
    # remove the vertical grid lines
    panel.grid.major.x = element_blank(),
    panel.border = element_blank(), axis.line.x = element_line()
  ) +
  scale_y_continuous(labels = unit_format(unit = "M", scale = 1e-6))+
  xlab("Age group") 
#> Warning: Ignoring unknown aesthetics: text
ggplot_obj
#> Warning: Use of `Cum$Cases` is discouraged. Use `Cases` instead.
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2021-06-05 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>

**Updated: adjust the geom_text position to be on top of bar instead.**

Answer (score 0):

The `size` aesthetic in `geom_bar()` applies to the `col` aesthetic, i.e. how wide the lines around the bar should be. In your current code, altering the `size` makes no difference because you have not mapped any attribute to the `col` aesthetic.

I recommend putting the male and female bars side-by-side rather than stacked by changing `position = "stacked"` to `position = "dodge"` in `geom_bar()`.

Then it looks to me like all of the data is represented in the plot. It's a bit odd because your `Range` variable nearly perfectly coincides with your `Age.group` variable.

Here is your plotting code with `text` and `size` aesthetic removed from `geom_bar()`, with result below:

```
ggplot(data = Cum, aes(x = `Age.group`, y = Cases, group = Gender, fill = Range)) +
  geom_bar(position = "dodge", stat = "identity") +
  geom_text(aes(y = Cases + 10000, label = Gender), vjust = 1,
            position = position_dodge(width=0.9),size=2) +
  scale_fill_manual(values = lbls) +
  coord_cartesian(ylim = c(0, max(Cum$Cases)*1.1), expand = FALSE) +
  theme_bw()+ theme(
    # remove the vertical grid lines
    panel.grid.major.x = element_blank(),
    panel.border = element_blank(), axis.line.x = element_line()
  ) +
  scale_y_continuous(labels = unit_format(unit = "M", scale = 1e-6))+
  xlab("Age group")
```

[image: Plot I produced by altering OP's code]

Comment: I Know the dodge solution but I want it stacked